# What is Spring boot 2.5 junit version?

Tags: spring-boot, junit5

I am using latest version of spring boot. What is spring boot `2.5.4` junit version?

```
spring-boot-starter-test
```

And for use Junit5 we should addd jupiter dependency in spring boot `2.5.4`?

Comment: The `spring-boot-starter-test` starter includes JUnit 5. [Spring Boot 2.4 removed JUnit 5's vintage engine](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.4-Release-Notes). To continue using JUnit 4, add the vintage engine dependency.

Answer (score 2):

On the [mvnrepository.com](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-test/2.5.4) you will find it:

> org.junit.jupiter » junit-jupiter

Version

> 5.7.2

There you can also click on [`pom.xml`](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-test/2.5.4/spring-boot-starter-test-2.5.4.pom) to show the dependency in question:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
    <version>5.7.2</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Note: `junit-jupiter` is a _transitive_ dependency in `spring-boot-starter-test`. It has default [scope `compile`](https://www.baeldung.com/maven-dependency-scopes#1-compile), so you don't need to add it separately to your project (POM) - it is included with the test starter already.